# encrypting uri segments in Codeigniter

Tags: url, codeigniter, security, codeigniter-url

I want to encrypt my uri segments that are passed as IDs to query into database tables.

For example I'm using

```
$id=urlencode($this->encrypt->encode($user['id']));
```

which is decode on another controller using

```
$id_decrypt=$this->encrypt->decode(urldecode($id));
```

I have tested the encryption and decription and it seems to work. However on trying the urls eg.

```
http://localhost/app_name/index.php/profile/view_profile/b98N98YNqoEA7yI1tavIY1s51RhiSHKGCFarU4A6XgFUMB%2BI3KwiEA23h1XITmkq1qPABqGs8e1sdP16v4og8g%3D%3D
```

on some of the url it will work as expected but on some it will give browser error 404 (Object not found). On deleting the encrypted segment, I can access the index function. What could be the possible cause of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the file ./application/config/config.php there is a section for permitted uri chars.  The default characters are:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-;
```

In some projects, I have changed this too:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\'+,-=';
```

However, as the CodeIgniter Engineers state

> DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you're having is with the `+` sign. `%2B` turns into `+` when decoded. The Url Router for CI operates on the decoded url.

`+` is a special character in urls used to represent spaces. This could be tripping up the url router.

---

Update:

This may actually be related to the XSS Protection Script in CI. There's a list of accepted URL Characters that it checks inputs against. The encryption you're using does put lots of fun characters in your input. (`%3D` is `=`). These (including +) are probably what's tripping up.

To fix this:

- You can use a different encryption algorithm. One you know won't add funky characters.
- You can Base64 Encode your result. Base64 *shouldn't* return anything other than alphanumeric characters (*if I remember correctly*). But note it can make the result **larger** in length.
- (*NOT RECCOMENDED*) you can edit the 'allowed characters' in the xss filtering section of your CI Configuration.

Comment: it seems to be true, most urls that does not work has that %2B in it.Do you have any idea how i can remove it. And are there any other characters I should be concerned about apart from +? because a few urls do not have %2B but they are not working.

Comment: I have realized now that what is bringing problems is %2F which is '/'. Using Base64encode removes other characters but comes with = which also seems to have some problems with the router apparently.